# MYSQL JDBC Database connection issue

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.out.println("Error:"+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, the output displayed the error:

`Error:com.mysql.jdbc.driver`

Comment: are you using MySQL or MSSQL? can you please use `ex.printStackTrace();` in the catch block instead of that `System.out.println("Error:"+ex.getMessage());` and show us the full error please

Comment: Please tell us which jdbc driver you are using and how you set it up.

Comment: `Error:com.mysql.jdbc.driver`is not a complete error message.  Please post the ENTIRE message including the stack trace (format as code).

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong naming convention for Driver, it should be **"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"** instead of "com.mysql.jdbc.driver" ,here you are using small "d" for Driver and also make sure you have added required jar to your application **"mysql-connector.jar"**. Please use below code.

import java.sql.*;
public class Test 
{

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException
{

    try 
    {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
       System.out.println("Error:"+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}